# Facebook iOS SDK , share an image with a caption using ShareDialog (not GraphAPI)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using following code to share a picture to Facebook using ShareDialog. However I'm unable to set a caption to this. `params` does not have a property for a caption.

```
 FBPhotoParams *params = [[FBPhotoParams alloc] init];

        params.photos = @[image]; // this is an UIImage instance.


        [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:params
                                         clientState:nil
                                             handler:^(FBAppCall *call,
                                                       NSDictionary *results,
                                                       NSError *error) {
                                                 if (error) {
                                                     NSLog(@"Error: %@",
                                                           error.description);
                                                 } else {
                                                     NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                 }
                                             }];
```

However there's a different method to share a status update with a picture, but this methods allows to share an image as a web link.

```
presentMessageDialogWithLink:name:caption:description:picture:clientState:handler:
```

I want to share a local UIImage just like in my first approach, with a caption. Is this possible?

Comment: Explain the down vote pls?

Comment: yes..down voter should explain what is wrong with this question

Comment: Not my downvote, but you both realise that members are not obliged to explain any voting.

Comment: @SabreTooth down voting without commenting (unless for obvious reasons) doesn't help anyone. That's why you get this notification -> `Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.` No one is "obliged" to do anything here. Even answering. This is a community. We do things to help others, not because we are "obliged". Doing something which isn't helpful is not a community service.

Comment: I understand that, was just stating the fact that many (if not most) people are never going to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for captions via the photo share dialog. The user must type in the caption/message themselves.